# working around SecurityToken requirements if the org is using IP access restrictions?

Tags: integration, security-token

We are testing some enterprise integration plugins that seem to require a Security Token when setting up the connection to our org.  We are, however, not using the security token method, but rather restricting access via IP addresses.  According to the documentation it's an either-or situation.  If the plugin requires a security token, what are our options?

Comment: IP Restriction should still let you get a Security Token and supply it ?

Comment: Contact the vendor - they should let you specify an 'empty' security token.

Answer (score 2):

Any vendor which *requires* a security token is distributing broken software, since the token is only required only if the API tells you it is required (i.e. it fails with "Are you at a new location...?"). This should be reported to the vendor for a fix. As you've observed, the only time the token is required is when you're not using IP restrictions, since the system assumes that any system that is within the IP range specified in an IP restriction is automatically granted access when the username and password are correct.